# When use entity framework core instead of entity framework

Tags: orm, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I am doing some research on EF core. I found that there are many similar features in both EF and EF core. So I wonder in which case we should use EF core instead of EF :)
Thanks!

Comment: Each time when you need something from EF Core roadmap https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap.

Comment: Big thank @IlyaChumakov. Your reference giving me a big picture for what EF core currently is!

Answer (score 2):

**Entity Framework Core**

- Cross Platform
- Lightweight
- Few database providers (because it's new)
- Missing some features from EF6 (again because it's new)

**Entity Framework 6**

- Tried and tested product
- Runs on .NET Framework
- Many database providers
- Not cross platform